# Journey Builder - BCC Email Address

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I configured a journey in Marketing Cloud where i sent an email. My requirement is adding BCC email addresses to this email, but I noticed that we can only add valid email addresses.
Could you confirm me that is not possible to add BCC /CC Address using personalization strings or Ampscript functions (e.g. Lookup) inside the Journey Email's settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's possibile to manage this use case ;) 
Before you need to open a case to request the activation of the CC and BCC feature.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just received feedback from salesforce marketing cloud technical support and they confirmed me that at this time it is not possible to include a personalization string or ampscript function in the bcc or cc field of the journey builder email activity. It will only accept one valid email address.

Comment: This is no longer the case. You can add multiple addresses and personalization strings or inline AMPscript is now supported. Refer to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/325631/5449).