# Send email to multiple email ID in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I have a data extension with a Text field containing a comma separated list of email recipients. Would I be able to use this field as Email Recipient in a journey?

I see one possible way would be to Create an email ID field in the Data Extension containing one of the email ID from this list. And save the rest of the email ID as text fields. Then use ampscript to send emails to both the fields.

Can someone help with this ampscript - cause I do not see a direct function to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A send email activity in Journey Builder only sends to one email address, which is the one of the contact that entered the journey. The desired behavior isn't possible without processing the data before the journey entry.

**Further reading:**

- [Send Email Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/configuring_the_send_email_activity/)
- [Journey Builder - BCC Email Address](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/176855/36218)

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I was reading the first comment in this discussion : https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00002ozUwk and was wondering how we can do it in a journey.

Comment: This is different to what you are trying to achieve according to your question. If you have multiple fields of type EmailAddress in your data extension and you like to send to lets say an alternative address, you can set *Default Channel Address* in the *Journey Settings* to send to that address. [Documentation article "Journey Settings"](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/)

Comment: is it so? Then I confused it with my requirement. Handling multiple email address fields in the Data extension is something I already do. Thanks for clarifying this.