# Add CC/BCC in Journey Builder email send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I can swear the option was there, but now I can't find it - any clues where it's gone and how to enable it?

Here is what I see now:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a functionality that is enabled at your account level. You need to ask the support to enable it for you.

> **CC and BCC:** 
>   When enabled in your account, carbon copy or blind carbon
>   copy recipients to an email send who are not members of the targeted
>   audience. Access is free and you are charged for each CC and BCC email
>   sent.

Reference: [Select Audience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_select_audience.htm&type=5)

Comment: thanks, I opened a case with support!

Answer (score 2):

For reference anyone searching to enable BCC/CC this is now self-service

"[Enable Email Studio Features in Marketing Cloud Setup](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2019_email_studio_features.htm&type=5)"

Enable one or more of these features in Email Optional Features.

HTML Paste
Double Opt-In
From Name Dropdown of Users
Send Throttling
BCC Emails
Impression Tracking
Text-only Email

Answer (score 0):

The steps needed:

1. enable the BCC features: Setup -> Feature Settings -> Email Studio -> Email Optional Features
2. log out and log in again (yes, this was needed in my case!)

Now the option is there:

- for multi-step journey it's in the email action under "advanced options" (screenshot below)
- for single send journeys it's in the "manage contacts" step, see [Journey Builder - BCC Email Address](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176822/journey-builder-bcc-email-address)

[image]