# Using Salesforce I am unable to use a variable in the BCC field which is set in the email header

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

We have CC and BCC enabled on our Salesforce account.
I am trying to send a BCC email to TrustPilot to trigger a review email.

The issue I have is that I need the email address to change based on language which is set in the header of the email and the BCC field is not reading this as a variable and only works when a specific address is entered.

I am using the following ampscript to call in the variable directly in the BCC field `%%=v(@BCCLink)=%%` 
This variable works correctly in both the email body and the subject line so the variable is getting set and rendered correctly elsewhere in the email.

We have multiple TrustPilot accounts so we cannot use their AFS code snippet to decide on the language and must do this using Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include a personalization string or inline AMPscript function in the CC or BCC field as this is not evaluated by OMM. You can only enter a single valid email address in this field.

The only solution would be to send the email separately to the desired CC/BCC recipient (for example, create a separate journey or batch send).

**Update**

After further testing, this is possible (it didn't used to be the case). You can use personalization strings or inline AMPscript in CC/BCC fields: For example:

`%%BCCAddress%%`

or

`%%=Lookup('DE Name', 'BCCAddress', 'SubscriberKey', _subscriberKey)=%%`

Answer (score 2):

You are able to use personalization strings like %%Accountowner%% in the BCC/CC but you can not reference a VAR from the email

To accomplish your use case you should pass the value you want to send to in a field within the TSDE, and use that field in the bcc/cc area